# Java: count of elements in a list

Tags: java, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to count occurrence of an element in a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505928/how-to-count-occurrence-of-an-element-in-a-list)

I have a list like `List<String> A={12, 12, 14, 16, 16}`. How can I find the number of elements distinctly as

```
12->2
14->1
16->2
```

by using a function like `countElements(A,"12")` or `A.count("12")`? Is there a library or a function?

Comment: You can find this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505928/how-to-count-occurrence-of-an-element-in-a-list very useful.

Answer (score 4):

Just iterate through each and maintain a

```
Map<Integer, Integer> numberToFrequencyMap;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also utililize the method [`Collections.frequency`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency%28java.util.Collection%2C%20java.lang.Object%29) if you need the frequency of only some of the elements individually.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`Apache Commons`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/)  [`CollectionUtils#getCardinalityMap`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#getCardinalityMap%28java.util.Collection%29)

It returns a `Map<Element, Integer>` with frequency of each element in your list.

```
List<String> list = {"12", "12", "14", "16", "16"};
Map<String, Integer> frequencyMapping = CollectionUtils.getCardinalityMap(list);
```

Also, you have a [`CollectionUtils#cardinality`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#cardinality%28java.lang.Object,%20java.util.Collection%29) if you want to fetch count for a specific element.

Comment: Why would you have to cast here?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yeah, no need. I got confused whether it returns `Map<? extends Object, Integer>`..

Answer (score 1):

If you can use third-party dependencies, [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has a collection type for this called [`Multiset`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multiset):

```
Multiset<String> multiset = HashMultiset.create(list);
multiset.count("foo"); // number of occurrences of foo
multiset.elementSet(); // returns the distinct strings in the multiset as a Set
multiset.entrySet(); // returns a Set<Multiset.Entry<String>> that you can 
 // iterate over to get the strings and their counts at the same time
```

(Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)

Comment: +1 for the contribution. Rest is all Child's play for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Iterate your numbers, maintain the count in a `Map` as below:

```
    List<Integer> myNumbers= Arrays.asList(12, 12, 14, 16, 16);
    Map<Integer, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for(int i=0; i<myNumbers.size(); i++){
        Integer myNum = myNumbers.get(i);
        if(countMap.get(myNum)!= null){
             Integer currentCount = countMap.get(myNum);
             currentCount = currentCount.intValue()+1;
             countMap.put(myNum,currentCount);
        }else{
            countMap.put(myNum,1);
        }
    }

   Set<Integer> keys = countMap.keySet();
   for(Integer num: keys){
       System.out.println("Number "+num.intValue()+" count "+countMap.get(num).intValue());
   }
```