# Elegant way of counting occurrences in a java collection

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, count

Given a collection of objects with possible duplicates, I'd like end up with a count of occurrences per object. I do it by initializing an empty `Map`, then iterating through the `Collection` and mapping the object to its count (incrementing the count each time the map already contains the object).

```java
public Map<Object, Integer> countOccurrences(Collection<Object> list) {
    Map<Object, Integer> occurrenceMap = new HashMap<Object, Integer>();
    for (Object obj : list) {
        Integer numOccurrence = occurrenceMap.get(obj);
        if (numOccurrence == null) {
            //first count
            occurrenceMap.put(obj, 1);
        } else {
            occurrenceMap.put(obj, numOccurrence++);
        }
    }
    return occurrenceMap;
}
```

This looks too verbose for a simple logic of counting occurrences. Is there a more elegant/shorter way of doing this? I'm open to a completely different algorithm or a java language specific feature that allows for a shorter code.

Comment: Counting occurrences is not that simple after all, your code seems to be the best you can do.

Comment: In order to have a complete list of occurrences of all elements, you will have to traverse the whole collection and I think your implementation is a decent one.

Comment: What makes you think this is verbose? Looks pretty clear to me. It's Just what Java looks like.

Comment: If the objects you are using implement Comparable interface, you can Collections.Sort the collection and make the count in a single iteration. Using map to store the data is ok IMO.

Comment: @DariuszWawer it is one iteration anyway, sorting won;t make a difference here.

Comment: @NimChimpsky my bad; I meant less overhead while searching and putting the object to the list every time. If you sort the collection you only require one put per one distinct object.

Comment: @Joe No good reason really. A programmer's hunch? Seemed to me like a simple piece of logic, but I couldn't figure out a better way to implement it other than the one above.

Comment: @DariuszWawer that makes even less sense. If you have an answer that is better with a sort post it (I can't see how you could).

Comment: @NimChimpsky posted it. Will you be so nice to admit that I am not wrong and what I wrote makes (at least some) sense? I feel that what you wrote is a bit too strong and even mildly insulting.

Comment: There is mistake in this code. It should be `++numOccurrence` in `else` statement otherwise we are overwriting the number of occurrences with 1.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Check out [Guava's Multiset](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained). Pretty much exactly what you're looking for.

Unfortunately it doesn't have an addAll(Iterable iterable) function, but a simple loop over your collection calling add(E e) is easy enough.

**EDIT**

My mistake, it does indeed have an addAll method - as it must, since it implements Collection.

Comment: Alternately, `Iterables.addAll(Collection, Iterable)`.

Answer (score 21):

Now let's try some Java 8 code:

```java
static public Map<String, Integer> toMap(List<String> lst) {
    return lst.stream()
            .collect(HashMap<String, Integer>::new,
                    (map, str) -> {
                        if (!map.containsKey(str)) {
                            map.put(str, 1);
                        } else {
                            map.put(str, map.get(str) + 1);
                        }
                    },
                    HashMap<String, Integer>::putAll);
}
```

```java
static public Map<String, Integer> toMap(List<String> lst) {
    return lst.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s,
                                  Collectors.counting()));
}
```

I think this code is more elegant.

Comment: Maybe I was searching for the wrong terms, but this Java 8 example was REALLY hard to find elsewhere, thanks for posting!

Comment: Just curious as to why you provide the verbose method and non-verbose? Note also that static imports of `Collectors.*` also makes this less verbose and in many situations nulls the need for the static method as it could often be tailed off an existing stream.

Comment: Even more elegant with the accumulator like this: `(map, str) -> map.merge(str, 1, (old, one) -> old+one)`

Comment: Collectors.counting produces a Long, so the return type should be Map<String,Long>

Comment: Adding to @Witbrock's comment: If you want a ``Map<String, Integer>``, you could use ``Collectors.reducing(0, e -> 1, Integer::sum)`` instead of ``Collectors.counting()``.

Answer (score 14):

I know this is an old question, but I've found a more elegant way in Java 8 for counting these votes, hope you like it.

```
Map<String, Long> map = a.getSomeStringList()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    Function.identity(),
                    Collectors.counting())
            );
```

Any error, just comment.

Answer (score 7):

Check this article [How to count the number of occurrences of an element in a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505928/how-to-count-occurrence-of-an-element-in-a-list). For counting occurences you can use `int occurrences = Collections.frequency(list, obj);`.

Comment: `Collections.frequency` is good to count some specific objects. But what OP needs is to count all objects' frequency, which makes this method very inefficient.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware of this method. In my case however, I'd like to count occurrences of all unique objects in the collection in a single pass.

Comment: I agree, it's inefficient. It was just a suggestion of a method from the native Java library for this task. I don't know any others, that solve exactly this problem, use external ones then.

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice article on counters in java here: http://www.programcreek.com/2013/10/efficient-counter-in-java/ it focuses more on efficiency than elegance though.

The winner was this:

```
HashMap<String, int[]> intCounter = new HashMap<String, int[]>();
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ITERATIONS; i++) {
    for (String a : sArr) {
        int[] valueWrapper = intCounter.get(a);

        if (valueWrapper == null) {
            intCounter.put(a, new int[] { 1 });
        } else {
            valueWrapper[0]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not that verbose for Java. You can use `TObjectIntHashMap`:

```java
public <T> TObjectIntHashMap<T> countOccurrences(Iterable<T> list) {
    TObjectIntHashMap<T> counts = new TObjectIntHashMap<T>();
    for (T obj : list) counts.adjustOrPut(obj, 1, 1);
    return counts;
}
```

Comment: is this better than the guava option ?

Comment: @NimChimpsky If by better you mean faster, yes.  MultiSet might be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the below solution to count every element in collections.

For Integer Value:

```java
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(3);
list.add(2);
list.add(5);
list.add(1);
list.add(8);
list.add(0);
list.add(2);
list.add(32);
list.add(72);
list.add(0);
list.add(13);
list.add(32);
list.add(73);
list.add(22);
list.add(73);
list.add(73);
list.add(21);
list.add(73);

HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();

for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
    set.add(list.get(j));
}

Iterator<Integer> itr = set.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    int a = itr.next();
    System.out.println(a + " : " + Collections.frequency(list, a));
}
```

Output:

```
0 : 2
32 : 2
1 : 1
2 : 2
3 : 1
5 : 1
21 : 1
22 : 1
8 : 1
72 : 1
73 : 4
13 : 1
```

For String Value:

```java
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
stringList.add("ABC");
stringList.add("GHI");
stringList.add("ABC");
stringList.add("DEF");
stringList.add("ABC");
stringList.add("GHI");

HashSet<String> setString = new HashSet<>();

for (int j = 0; j < stringList.size(); j++) {
    setString.add(stringList.get(j));
}

Iterator<String> itrString = setString.iterator();
while (itrString.hasNext()) {
    String a = itrString.next();
    System.out.println(a + " :::  " + Collections.frequency(stringList, a));
}
```

Output:

```
ABC :::  3
DEF :::  1
GHI :::  2
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised no one offered this simple and readable solution. You could just use [Map#getOrDefault()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-).

```
 public Map<Object, Integer> countOccurrences(Collection<Object> list){
      Map<Object, Integer> occurrenceMap = new HashMap<Object, Integer>();
      for(Object obj: list){
          occurrenceMap.put(obj, occurrenceMap.getOrDefault(obj, 0) + 1);
      }
      return occurrenceMap;
 }
```

It solves exactly the problem you have and removes the clunky `if..else`.

Comment: I hoped no one posted this answer so I could write it but you did :'D.

Answer (score 0):

As a response to discussion with @NimChimpsky here is an alternative and faster - which I am attempting to prove - method of counting which uses a sorted collection. Depending on the number of elements and the "sortFactor" (see code) the speed difference varies, but for large amounts of objects in Run environment (not debug) my method has a 20-30% speed increase in relation to default method.
Here is a simple test class for both methods.

```
public class EltCountTest {

    final static int N_ELTS = 10000;

    static final class SampleCountedObject implements Comparable<SampleCountedObject>
    {
        int value = 0;

        public SampleCountedObject(int value) {
            super();
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(SampleCountedObject o) {
            return (value == o.value)? 0:(value > o.value)?1:-1; // just *a* sort
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj instanceof SampleCountedObject) {
                return value == ((SampleCountedObject)obj).value;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "SampleCountedObject("+value+")";
        }
    }

    /**
     * * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int tries = 10000;
        int sortFactor = 10;
        Map<SampleCountedObject, Integer> map1 = null;
        Map<SampleCountedObject, Integer> map2 = null;

        ArrayList<SampleCountedObject> objList = new ArrayList<EltCountTest.SampleCountedObject>(N_ELTS);

        for (int i =0, max=N_ELTS/sortFactor; i<max; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j<sortFactor; j++) {
                objList.add(new SampleCountedObject(i));
            }
        }

        long timestart = System.nanoTime();
        for (int a=0; a< tries; a++) {
            map1 = method1(objList);
        }
        System.out.println();
        long timeend1 = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println();

        for (int a=0; a< tries; a++) {
            map2 = metod2(objList);
        }
        long timeend2 = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println();


        long t1 = timeend1-timestart;
        long t2 = timeend2-timeend1;
        System.out.println("\n        org count method=["+t1+"]\nsorted collection method=["+t2+"]"+
                 "\ndiff=["+Math.abs(t1-t2)+"] percent=["+(100d*t2/t1)+"]");

        for (SampleCountedObject obj: objList) {
            int val1 = map1.get(obj);
            int val2 = map2.get(obj);
            if (val1 != val2) {
                throw new RuntimeException("val1 != val2 for obj "+obj);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("veryfy OK");

    }

    private static Map<SampleCountedObject, Integer> method1(ArrayList<SampleCountedObject> objList) {
        Map<SampleCountedObject, Integer> occurenceMap = new HashMap<SampleCountedObject, Integer>();

        for(SampleCountedObject obj: objList){
             Integer numOccurrence = occurenceMap.get(obj);
             if(numOccurrence == null){
                 occurenceMap.put(obj, 1);
             } else {
                 occurenceMap.put(obj, ++numOccurrence);
             }
        }
        return occurenceMap;
    }

    private static Map<SampleCountedObject, Integer> metod2(ArrayList<SampleCountedObject> objList) {
        Map<SampleCountedObject, Integer> occurenceMap = new HashMap<SampleCountedObject, Integer>();
        int count = 0;
        Collections.sort(objList);
        SampleCountedObject prevObj = objList.get(0);

        for(SampleCountedObject obj: objList){
            if (!obj.equals(prevObj)) {
                occurenceMap.put(prevObj, count);
                count = 1;
            } else {
                count ++;
            }
            prevObj = obj;
        }
        occurenceMap.put(prevObj, count);
        return occurenceMap;
    }
}
```

Note that I also verify that the results are the same and I do it after printing the test results.

What I found interesting is that in Debug run my method is fairly slower than the original (10-20%, again - depending on the number of elements in collection).

Comment: You are generating an already-sorted list, so you aren't even getting to see the real perfomance hit of doing a sort. For the first method, time complexity is O(n). Yours is O(n) PLUS the sorting method, which will probably be O(n log n), or as bad as O(n^2). Basically all you've done (besides the sort) is replace the hashmap get() with equals(). I really don't think that gives much savings (they are both O(1) ) unless you have data specifically optimized for your method (so probably never in the real world)

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in `commons-collections`: `CollectionUtils.getCardinalityMap` which is doing exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`Bag`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/10.4.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/bag/Bag.html) from [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections).

```
Iterable<Object> iterable = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3");
MutableBag<Object> counts = Bags.mutable.withAll(iterable);

Assertions.assertEquals(1, counts.occurrencesOf("1"));
Assertions.assertEquals(2, counts.occurrencesOf("2"));
Assertions.assertEquals(3, counts.occurrencesOf("3"));
Assertions.assertEquals(0, counts.occurrencesOf("4"));
```

The `withAll` method on the `MutableBagFactory` interface takes an `Iterable` as a parameter, and returns a `MutableBag`. The method `occurrencesOf` on `MutableBag` returns an `int`, which is the number of occurrences of an element. Unlike a `Map`, a `Bag` will not return `null` if it does not contain an element. Instead, the `occurrencesOf` method will return `0`.

`MutableBag` is a `Collection`, so it has an `addAll` method that takes a `Collection` as a parameter.

```
counts.addAll(Arrays.asList("4", "4", "4", "4"));
Assertions.assertEquals(4, counts.occurrencesOf("4"));
```

`MutableBag` also has an `addAllIterable` method which takes `Iterable`.

```
Stream<Object> stream = Stream.of("1", "2", "3", "4");
counts.addAllIterable(stream::iterator);

Assertions.assertEquals(2, counts.occurrencesOf("1"));
Assertions.assertEquals(3, counts.occurrencesOf("2"));
Assertions.assertEquals(4, counts.occurrencesOf("3"));
Assertions.assertEquals(5, counts.occurrencesOf("4"));
```

The `HashBag` implementation in Eclipse Collections is backed by an `ObjectIntHashMap`, so the `int` counts are not boxed. There is a blog with more information about the `Bag` type in Eclipse Collections located [here](https://medium.com/oracledevs/bag-the-counter-2689e901aadb).

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections

Answer (score -1):

Java is a verbose language, I don't think there is a simpler way to achieve that, unless using 3rd-party library or waiting for Java 8's Lambda Expression.

Comment: Compared to ruby, python, perl, Scala, C# etc. A lot.

Comment: Can anybody give me a reason for downvoting this answer? Is accepted answer using 3rd-party library? Just because I'm saying Java is verbose? How funny is that.

Comment: I would suggest it's contentious at least, and as such will attract such responses.