# Checking which elements are the same in an array

Tags: java

Im trying to check which elements are the same in an array and then return the elements that are the same. Im thinking that i have to do a for loop inside of a for loop but im not sure. This is what i have so far:

```
for (int p = 0 ; p < temperatures.length ; p++) {
    for (int j = 0 ; j < temperatures.length ; j++) {
        if (temperatures[p] == temperatures[j]) {
            System.out.println("matching" + j + p);
        }
    }
}
```

How i created the array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < temperatures.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the temperature in Celcius for day " + (i+1));
    temperatures[i] = new Data(input.nextDouble());
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you encounter?

Comment: if temperatures are double or float, maybe you should compare each other using some delta

Comment: Is this a homework, or something like that? If not, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14260134/elegant-way-of-counting-occurrences-in-a-java-collection) SO question.

Comment: When i putt in input for the 7 temperatures it says theres 7 matches because i think its matching each element to itself

Comment: Hey, I think you can find useful the answer presented here. I think it is very close to what you want to do and it is well explained. Regards and happy coding :). URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951547/java-array-finding-duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it says 7 matches is due to

```
for(int j = 0; j < temperatures.length; j++)
            {
                if(temperatures[p] == temperatures[j]) // This will have te..[0]==te..[0] .... te..[1]==te..[1] .... te..[6]==te..[6]
```

You should change it to

```
for(int j = p+1; j < temperatures.length; j++)
            {
                if(temperatures[p] == temperatures[j]) //Here there's no chance of p==j. So this will work.
```

Comment: I did what you suggested, I am getting 0 matches when i putt all of the temperatures the same?>

Comment: I've updated my code int j= i+1; to int j=p+1;   As p is the variable which you're declaring in the first for loop, by running this code in my Eclipse, I'm getting correct output.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to first sort the array (as long as they are number or can be sorted). Then checking for duplicates is trivial.

Sorting with `QuickSort` or `TimSort` is `O(n log n)` average, and you can tell duplicates in `O(n)`. If you cannot modify the original then you will need an extra `O(n)` in space and time (to copy).

Note that [`Arrays.sort(double[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(double[])) is `O(n log n)`.

This algorithm is `O(2n log n)` which is `O(n log n) = O(log n!)`.

Simple example with random ints.

```
        int[] d = ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(100, 0, 100).toArray();
    Arrays.sort(d); // O(n log n)

    boolean dup = false;
    for (int i = 1; i < d.length; i++) { // O(n)
        if (d[i - 1] == d[i]) {
            dup = true;
        } else {
            if (dup) {
                System.out.print(d[i - 1] + " ");
            }
            dup = false;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");

    for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(d[i] + " ");
    }
```