# how to find number of same value in a array list using java

Tags: java

I have array list with value like

```
x-tag
125
154
166
125
125
222
125
```

In above list,it has value `125` for `4` time
I have the value `125` from another and i can check whether list having 125 or not.
But not able to find how many times it occur or present in list

Comment: What sort of stuff have you tried?

Comment: `counter` is you friend. BTW, Where is your code ?

Comment: How about adding the code you already have to check whether the number is present or not? Hints can flow from there

Comment: Here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505928/how-to-count-occurrence-of-an-element-in-a-list

Answer (score 11):

Use [`Collections#frequency()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency%28java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object%29) method:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(125, 154, 166, 125, 125, 222, 125);
int totalCount = Collections.frequency(list, 125);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Guava libraries [Multiset](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release02/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html), elements of a `Multiset` that are equal to one another are referred to as occurrences of the same single element.

```
Multiset<Integer> myMultiset = HashMultiset.create();
myMultiset.addAll(list);
System.out.println(myMultiset.count(125)); // 4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(125,154,166,125,125,222,125);

int count = Collections.frequency(list, 125);

System.out.println("total count: " + tcount);
```

Output:

```
total count: 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Also possible to map it into a map. Bit more code though:

```
package com.stackoverflow.counter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Count {
    public Map<Integer,Integer> convertToMap(List<Integer> integerList) {
        Map<Integer,Integer> integerMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (Integer i: integerList) {
            Integer numberOfOccurrences = integerMap.get(i);
            if (numberOfOccurrences == null)
                numberOfOccurrences = 0;
            integerMap.put(i,++numberOfOccurrences);
        }
        return integerMap;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<>();
        integerList.add(1);
        integerList.add(3);
        integerList.add(2);
        integerList.add(1);
        integerList.add(3);
        integerList.add(2);
        integerList.add(4);
        integerList.add(5);
        integerList.add(5);
        Count count = new Count();
        Map<Integer, Integer> integerMap = count.convertToMap(integerList);
        for (Integer i: integerMap.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("Number: " + i + ", found " + integerMap.get(i) + " times.");
        }
    }
}
```