# Count Specific word on ArrayList<String>

Tags: java

Imagine that you have this situation:

```
List<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
    al.add("[I] am");
    al.add("you are");
    al.add("I");
    al.add("[I] like java");
```

Now I want to count the sequence [I] (in this case it will count 2 times). The Link [How to count the number of occurrences of an element in a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505928/how-to-count-occurrence-of-an-element-in-a-list) just pust one word, but on my example I have more than one, i.e, Collections.frequency(al, "[I]") do not work.

How can I achieve this preferentially using Java 8 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way is to split the stream by space and then check whether chunk is equal to `[I]` e.g.

```
System.out.println(al.stream().map((w) -> w.split(" ")).flatMap(Arrays::stream).filter((i) ->i.equals("[I]")).count());
```

Using `equals` have advantage over contains because let say your list contains words like below

```
List<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
        al.add("[I] am [I]");
        al.add("you are");
        al.add("I");
        al.add("[I] like java");
```

This solution will return 3 as expected but the solution mentioned by Bohuslav Burghardt will return 2