# How does one Convert a List to Map with Java-8 Streams where Key is the ListValue and the Value is the amount of values of that specific list

Tags: java, java-8

This is my list:

```
List<Card> cards;
```

my Java-8 stream where i want to create the Map

```
Map<String, Integer> cardsMap = cards.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Card::getCardValue, amount of cards that are grouped));
```

This obviously doesn't work but i am clueless of how i would do it otherwise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 List<V> into Map<K, V>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363719/java-8-listv-into-mapk-v)

Comment: as far as i can see it doesn't describe how i would make the value a count of all the grouped items

Comment: Post your pre-Java 8 code that produces the desired result.

Comment: sure, gona try to make it, didn't make it since i am trying to get familliar with java8

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is this what you meant?

```
    Map<String, Long> cardsMap = cards
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Card::getCardValue, Collectors.counting()));
```

It will give you a map from card values to counts of cards with that value in your original list. For example, if you have:

```
    List<Card> cards = Arrays.asList(new Card("4"), new Card("8"), new Card("4"));
```

(and I know I’ve probably reduced your `Card()` constructor), the above will map `"4"` to 2 and `"8"` to 1.

Comment: just found it myself, but yes that was basically how one should do it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is how to do it:

```
Map<String, Long> cardsMap = cards.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getCardValue(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Here are more ways:
[How to count the number of occurrences of an element in a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505928/how-to-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list)