# Java 8 count number of duplicates for each String in ArrayList of ArrayLists

Tags: java-8, java-stream, collectors

I need to count a number of occurrences for each string in

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>
```

I know how to do it the old java 7 and below way, but want to do it using streams and collectors
Ideally, I would save the result in the `HashMap<String, Integer>`, where integer is a number of occurrences and String is the corresponding string.

This can be vice versa - not a big deal.

I found solution how to do it for `ArrayList` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505928/how-to-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list)

```
Map<String, Long> counts =
    list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

but my case is more complex since it's an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`s.

The structure is following

`String itemId = list.get(i).getProducts().get(j).getItemId();`

Comment: What do you mean with “count number of duplicates”? Do you rather mean “number of occurrences”?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to count the number of occurrences, regardless of in which sub-list the strings appear, you can use

```
Map<String, Long> counts = list.stream().flatMap(List::stream)
   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()));
```

if having `Integer` as value type is important to you, you can use

```
Map<String, Integer> counts = list.stream().flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1)));
```

instead.

Additionally, a solution based on conventional loops can also benefit from Java 8 features:

```
Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
for(List<String> l: list)
    for(String s: l)
        counts.merge(s, 1, Integer::sum);
```

Comment: I am getting the following error  (for the first option that you mentioned).
Multiple markers at this line
 - Stream cannot be resolved
 - Type mismatch: cannot convert from Stream<Object> to 
  <unknown>

Comment: Well, if it says, “Stream cannot be resolved”, you have serious problems in your project setup, as the code above doesn’t contain any reference to `Stream`. But still, check whether you have correctly imported every type you are using. Or do you mean “stream” (lowercase)? The code above assumes that you have an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` as you stated in your question, not anything having a `getProducts()` method as appended to it five days later.

Comment: You can fix it by changing `.flatMap(List::stream)` to `.flatMap(o->o.getProducts().stream())`, but in the future, provide a correct problem description right when you post your question initially.