# Count and remove similar elements in a list while iterating through it

Tags: java, list, addition, removeall

I used many references in the site to build up my program but I'm kind of stuck right now. I think using `iterator` will do the job. Sadly even though I went through questions which had iterator, I couldn't get the way of using it properly to implement it on my code.

I want to,
      1. remove the similar elements found in the list `fname` 
      2. count & add the that count of each element found in `fname` to 
          `counter`.

Please help me do the above using iterator or with any other method. Following is my code,

```
List<String> fname = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(fullname.split(""))); //Assigning the string to a list//

    int count = 1;
    ArrayList<Integer> counter = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> holder = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int element=0; element<=fname.size; element++)
    {
        for(int run=(element+1); run<=fname.size; run++)
        {
            if((fname.get(element)).equals(fname.get(run)))
            {
                count++;
                holder.add(fname.get(run));
            }

            counter.add(count);                    
        }

        holder.add(fname.get(element));
        fname.removeAll(holder);
    }

    System.out.println(fname);
    System.out.println(counter);
```

Thanks.

Comment: give us some samples of list content

Comment: @BasilBattikhi list fname : {a, d, e, a, a, f, t, d} so the list count should be like {3, 2, 1, 1, 1}

Comment: what the error you got?

Comment: or provide us with the expectation output  and what are you got

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that you need iterators here. However, there are many other possible solutions you could use, like recursion. Nevertheless, I have just modified your code as the following:

```
    final List<String> fname = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(fullname.split("")));
    // defining a list that will hold the unique elements.
    final List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
    // defining a list that will hold the number of replication for every item in the fname list; the order here is same to the order in resultList
    final ArrayList<Integer> counter = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int element = 0; element < fname.size(); element++) {
        int count = 1;
        for (int run = (element + 1); run < fname.size(); run++) {
            if ((fname.get(element)).equals(fname.get(run))) {
                count++;
                // we remove the element that has been already counted and return the index one step back to start counting over.
                fname.remove(run--);
            }
        }
        // we add the element to the resulted list and counter of that element
        counter.add(count);
        resultList.add(fname.get(element));
    }
    // here we print out both lists.
    System.out.println(resultList);
    System.out.println(counter);
```

Assuming `String fullname = "StringOfSomeStaff";` the output will be as the following:

```
[S, t, r, i, n, g, O, f, o, m, e, a]
[3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: I want something like, if  {s, t, r, i, n, g, o, f, s, o, m, e, s, t, a, f, f} is entered it should generate the count list as {3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1} which is as, No. of  s=3, t=2, r=1, i=1 etc. The counting of the elemrnts should be done as per their order in th list & the counted elements should be removed as  soon as they are counted.

Comment: I think I did it as you said.. I don't remove the counted element but I don't count it again; its counted only once.

Comment: Ok thanks. I still didn't try out the code. I'll let you know the result as soon as I check with it.

Comment: Sorry but I tried out the code & it do count the elements repeatedly. Just check with your example, at first under 'S' it has no. 3, again in the middle under 'S' it has no. 2. I counts the no. of remaining similar elements again when it come across a previously counted element if it's not deleted.

Comment: @Amaani .. I now understand what you really want; I have updated the code, check it once again.

Comment: Sorry but now it gives 2 blank lists as the output.

Comment: I have just tried it here ..  did you copy all the code?

Comment: I'm really really sorry. Last time I have copied your code without 2 lines. (Crazy me). It works 100% in the way I want. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Good! .. thats mean you will mark my answer as the correct answer! ;)

Comment: Sure. Can you please add comments to explain your code. It'll help me a lot as I'm just a beginner.

Comment: Sorry but I don't have enough reputations to upvote :(

Comment: Its Okay, I am just enjoying collecting credits. I just up-voted your question .. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks and Good Luck to you too.  :)

Answer (score 2):

From your questions, you basically want to:

**1. Eliminate duplicates from given String List**

You can simply convert your List to [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) (it doesn't allow duplicates) and then convert it back to list (if you want the end result to be a List so you can do something else with it...)

**2. Count all occurences of unique words in your list**
The fastest coding is to use Java 8 Streams (code borrowed frome here: [How to count the number of occurrences of an element in a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505928/how-to-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list))

**Complete code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fullname = "a b c d a b c"; //something
    List<String> fname = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(fullname.split(" ")));

    // Convert input to Set, and then back to List (your program output)
    Set<String> uniqueNames = new HashSet<>(fname);
    List<String> uniqueNamesInList = new ArrayList<>(uniqueNames);
    System.out.println(uniqueNamesInList);

    // Collects (reduces) your list
    Map<String, Long> counts = fname.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
    System.out.println(counts);
}
```

Comment: You can extract the uniqueNames directly from the Map with keySet().

Comment: @GuillaumeF. it's a `HashSet`, not a `HashMap`. Are you sure you can do that?

Comment: @MiguelKVidal `Set<String> uniqueNames = counts.keySet();` Also the List conversion is not useful, both are Collections.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. I checked the docs and haven't found this method in the Set interface: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html.
Are you really sure your aren't talking about the Map interface (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet--)?

Comment: @MiguelKVidal read my comment carefully, and see that I am referring to the variable `counts` which is a `Map`.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. now I see it! Sorry, it was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<>();
mySet.addAll( fname ); // Now you have unique values

for(String s : mySet) {
    count = 0;
    for(String x : fname) {
        if( s.equals(x) ) { count++; }
    }
    counter.add( count );
}
```

This way we don't have a specific order. But I hope it helps.

In Java 8, there's a one-liner:

```
List<Integer> result = fname
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s))
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(e -> e.getValue().size())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using LinkedHashMap to preserve order of elements. Also for loop, which I am using,  implicitly uses Iterator. Code example is using `Map.merge` method, which is available since Java 8.

```
    List<String> fname = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(fullname.split("")));
    /*
        Create Map which will contain pairs kay=values
        (in this case key is a name and value is the counter).
        Here we are using LinkedHashMap (instead of common HashMap)
        to preserve order in which name occurs first time in the list.
    */
    Map<String, Integer> countByName = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (String name : fname) {
        /*
             'merge' method put the key into the map (first parameter 'name').
             Second parameter is a value which we that to associate with the key
             Last (3rd) parameter is a function which will merge two values
             (new and ald) if map already contains this key
         */
        countByName.merge(name, 1, Integer::sum);
    }
    System.out.println(fname);                  // original list [a, d, e, a, a, f, t, d]
    System.out.println(countByName.values());   // counts [3, 2, 1, 1, 1]
    System.out.println(countByName.keySet());   // unique names [a, d, e, f, t]
```

Also same might be done using Stream API but it would be probably hard for understanding if you are not familiar with Streams.

```
    Map<String, Long> countByName = fname.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried it on my code & it worked exactly as I wanted. This is the first time that I came across this `Map` function. Thanks a lot. Please add comment lines describing the 2nd to 4th lines if you can so that I can clearly get what it does.