# Is there a better way to create a method that finds whether or not an integer value exists in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, methods

The program has an ArrayList of 50 grades, and one of the methods that is called is supposed find if a value exists in the ArrayList. This is what I have:

```
public void find(int g) {
int grade = 0;
if (grades.contains(g)) {
  grade++;
}
```

Did I do this right?

Comment: *a method that finds whether or not an integer value exists* - What is the point of using the "grade" variable? The variable is defined locally and not returned to a calling method, so it effectively does nothing. So I'm not really understanding the point of the method. I would have thought your method would simply return the boolean result of using the contains() method. Since it is a single statement I'm not sure why you would make it a method. I think you need to clarify your requirement.

Comment: If you want a count of the number of a kind of grade in an array list, then no.  This only finds the first occurrence, not the total.  It basically does the same thing as `contains()` alone.

Answer (score 2):

As @markspace commented:

> It basically does the same thing as `contains()` alone.

If you declare a void funciton, you might not be able to see the result.
So, the local variable `grade` actually does nothing.
Just do it:

```
public boolean isExist(int g) {
    return grades.contains(g);
}
```

---

If you want to calculate the number of occurrences of an element in your list:
Reference: [How to count the number of occurrences of an element in a List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505928/how-to-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list)

```java
int occurrences = Collections.frequency(grades, g);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code snippet you have posted, if your intent is to find out the count of grades that are >= a specified number, you could use the `filter` method like in the snippet below

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,10,10,10);
long count = list.stream().filter(i -> i == 10).count();
System.out.println("count:" + count);
```