# Filter and return value from a Map in Java 8

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I am learning Java 8 basics and kind of struggling with a simple problem. I have a program which basically gives me the non repeating element in an array. The implementation logic to achieve this is irrelevant here; I am struggling to return the value in Java 8.

```
public class Tetst
 {
  public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] arr = {1,2,2};
    singleNumber(arr);
}

public static int singleNumber(int[] nums) {
    HashMap<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    //int val = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if(!map.containsKey(nums[i])) {
            map.put(nums[i], 1);
        } else {
            map.put(nums[i], map.get(nums[i]) + 1);
        }
    }

    return map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(val -> val.getValue().equals(1))

    //         for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entrySet : map.entrySet()) {
    //             if(entrySet.getValue().equals(1)) {
    //                 val = entrySet.getKey();
    //             }
    //         }

    //         return val;

}
```

}

I know I have to filter the result but then how do I return that particular Key of this map..
In the commented section I was able to do it using Java 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but then how do I return that particular Key of this map.

```
return map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(val -> 
          val.getValue().equals(1))
          // map to the key and the return the first one found.
         .map(Entry::getKey).findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Note that you can change the `orElse` value to something more meaningful as long as it matches the key type.

If you want a fairly quick and efficient way to find all the non-dups in the array you can do the following.

```
int[] arr = { 1, 8, 2, 3, 8, 4, 9, 12, 2, 12, 8, 8, 9 };
```

Create two sets of the orginal array.

```
Set<Integer> vals = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

Set<Integer> distinct = new HashSet<>(vals);
```

Now simply iterate thru the array. If a value was not successfully removed from  the `vals` set it must be duplicate since it would have been removed earlier. So remove that from the `distinct` set.

```
for (int i : arr) {
    if (!vals.remove(i)) {
        distinct.remove(i);
    }
}

System.out.println(distinct);
```

prints

```
[1, 3, 4]
```

What makes this efficient is that most of the operations involve `HashSets` so the value is located very quickly as opposed to linearly searching a list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) and [findFirst](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) method. Therefore the code look like this:

```java
List<Integer> nums = List.of(1, 2, 2);
Map<Integer, Long> counts = nums.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
return counts.entrySet().stream().filter(val -> val.getValue().equals(1L)).map(Entry::getKey).findFirst().orElse(-1);
```

I found this answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27206052/10951752).